# saving and getting 3 ints and one string from one list

Tags: java, list, minecraft, bukkit

Hello I am making a new plugin for minecraft bukkit but I have to make a list of players with locations in it.

So I tought to make a list with 3 integers and one string.
The 3 ints are for the location and the string is for the player name.

but how do I make an list with 3 ints and one string and then how do I find the ints back on player name?

Example :
I save 3 ints and my playername
12, 20, 10 These are the coordinates
nobleleader13245 this is my player name

now I saved the stuff to the list and I want to get the coordinates back
so I search on playername in the list but how do I do this?

Sorry if my example is bad or if my English is bad I hope someone can help my out.

EDIT :

So now I have the code tieTYT suggested me it works but now I need to get it back from the list.
How do I do that?

So I think I have to look trough the list and compare the senders name with the listed players and if one of that is equal then get the ints but how? sorry I am a bit noob at Java, but I try to learn it!

Comment: Java is an object oriented programming language, so... make an object ! (i.e. a class containing the attributes you need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not idiomatic.  Instead, make a class that has 3 integers and 1 string in it, and then add this class to your List.

The only way to do what you're asking is to not put generics on the List, like so:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List rawInput = new ArrayList();
        rawInput.add(1);
        rawInput.add(2);
        rawInput.add(3);
        rawInput.add("s");                
    }

}
```

And, although this compiles, it's bad and gives you warnings, for good reason.  Instead, make a class like this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> rawInput = new ArrayList<Character>();
        rawInput.add(new Character("Foo", new Location(1, 2, 3)));        
    }

    public static class Character {

        private String name;

        private Location location;
        public Character(String name, Location location) {
            this.name = name;
            this.location = location;
        }
    }

    public static class Location {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int z;

        public Location(int x, int y, int z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok I get that but how do I get the location?

Comment: @Nobleleader13245 why would I be the one with that knowledge?

Comment: Well idk ;) well anyway thanks a lot I did come closer to what I want thanks.